# JSON List ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have /Views/Movies/Index.cshtml with

```
<input type="button" id="getmoviex" value="Get moviex" />
<ul id="moviex_list"/>
 <p>
        Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchTitle") <br />
    </p>
```

I have /Controllers/MoviesController.cs with

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult moviex(string SearchGenre, string SearchTitle, string SearchActor)
    {
        var db = new CinemaContext();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var Movie = from m in db.Movie
                    select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTitle))
        {
            Movie = Movie.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchTitle));
        }
         return Json(db.Movie.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have Javascript.js with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getmoviex').click(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Movies", null, getmoviex);
    });
});
```

Have I correctly written /Movies? Or this should be /Views/Movies?

```
function getmoviex(moviex) {
    $("#moviex_list").text("");
    $.each(moviex, function (i) {
        $("#moviex_list").append("<li>" + this + "</li>");
    });
}
```

**How can I display info or list info from my query?** Or view some output with error?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you button click does not trigger a request to server. Preventing default behavior is a standard way of doing it:

```
$('#getmoviex').click(function (event) {
    $.getJSON("/Movies", null, getmoviex);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

As for the URL, it should not be to view, but to action instead. Your action is moviex and controller is Movies, so

```
$.getJSON("/Movies/moviex", null, getmoviex);
```

The rest looks fine, so that should do it.

Comment: Thanks. I try $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getmoviex').click(function (event) {
        $.getJSON("/Movies/moviex", null, getmoviex);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}); //But This does not work

Comment: How to see them? I would try.

Comment: OK, i start it directly http://localhost:27161/Movies/moviex and get This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Comment: I remade return Json(db.Movie.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Movie_B1FE93473F6D1D9C6D1‌​FB5C5C23CAD32C5A4BE8‌​E694908458170AF6743A‌​A96B6'. –

Comment: var db = new CinemaContext();
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var Movie = from m in db.Movie
                        select m;

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass your arguments as well in url (`GET`).
Something like this could work:

```js
$('#getmoviex').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.getJSON("/Movies/moviex?SearchGenre=yuorgenre&SearchTitle=Cal&SearchActor=youractor", function(moviex) {
      var lis;
      //please check the console
      console.log(moviex);
      $.each(moviex, function(b) {
          lis += "<li id='" + b.Id + "'>" + b.Title + "</li>");
      }); document.getElementById("moviex_list").innerHTML += lis;
  });
});
```

To avoid circular reference in Serializing you may use:

```js
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTitle)) {
  return View("Error");
}

var db = new CinemaContext();
var Movie = (from m in db.Movie
            Where m.Title.Contains(SearchTitle)
            select new {
             Id = m.MovieID,
             Title = m.Title // can add more properties
            }).ToList();

return Json(Movie, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: i already wrote query for Movies and i created moviex for json.

Comment: On which part it did not work?
Was your `moviex` method in `Movies` controller triggered? - try to set breakpoint inside method or try to Run your project then in browser Location bar edit to something like
`localhost:xxxx/Movies/moviex?SearchGenre=yuorgenre&SearchTitle=a&SearchActor=youractor` and see what it return

Comment: OK, i start it directly http://localhost:27161/Movies/moviex and get This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Comment: I remade  return Json(db.Movie.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Movie_B1FE93473F6D1D9C6D1FB5C5C23CAD32C5A4BE8E694908458170AF6743AA96B6'.

Comment: I made var db = new CinemaContext();
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var Movie = from m in db.Movie
                        select m;

Comment: var Movie = (from m in db.Movie where m.Title.Contains(SearchTitle) select new {Title= m.Title}).ToList()

Comment: With all var when I clicking button I get [object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object] in output

Comment: I dont get it.  this one ` localhost:27161/Movies/moviex` has it return correct JSON already?

Comment: i return all my moves even I want just part of them. [{"MovieID":1,"Title":"Chemistry6","Date":"2013-09-01","Budget":10000,"Genre":null,"Actors":null},{"MovieID":2,"Title":"Chemistry Double","Date":"2014-09-01","Budget":78600,"Genre":"Comedy","Actors":null},{"MovieID":3,"Title":"Bond Double","Date":"2015-09-01","Budget":18600,"Genre":"Comedy","Actors":null}] But I wanna var Movie = (from m in db.Movie where m.Title.Contains("Chemistry6") select new { Title = m.Title }).ToList(); and I get all of them

Comment: I wanna run it by presiing the button not directly runnning function. And I get  [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] in output

Comment: And what was you returned? previously you `return Json(db.Movie.Tolist())` thats all movie. you should use `return Json(Movie, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` instead

Comment: I just wrote what I return in 2 case 1) directly run function 2) pressing the button

Comment: I wrote if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTitle)) {
  return View("Error");
} like you, And when I press button nothing appears. I get error when I run function directly

Comment: When I put in address bar http://localhost:27161//Movies/moviex?SearchTitle=Chemistry appears [{"MovieID":1,"Title":"Chemistry6","Date":"2013-09-01","Budget":10000,"Genre":null,"Actors":null},{"MovieID":2,"Title":"Chemistry Double","Date":"2014-09-01","Budget":78600,"Genre":"Comedy","Actors":null},{"MovieID":3,"Title":"Bond Double","Date":"2015-09-01","Budget":18600,"Genre":"Comedy","Actors":null}]

Comment: put breakpoint just before returning json in your controller. and try to inspect Movie value through `local window`

Comment: O would leatn ho to do it. :)